# My CSS selector doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why my paragraph don't become red when I select radiobutton with label?

```css
.radio-buttons {
  display: none;
}

.radio1:checked~p.chapter1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="radio1" id="radio1">
<label for="radio1">label</label>
<p class="chapter1">Some text</p>
```

Comment: `.radio1` Nothing has this class. Also, nothing in your example as the class `radio-buttons`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is for class.
`#` is for id.

```css
.radio-buttons {
  display: none;
}

#radio1:checked~p.chapter1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="radio1" id="radio1">
<label for="radio1">label</label>
<p class="chapter1">Some text</p>
```

Comment: Typos have their own close reason... Also, the answer doesn't fix the problem of `.radio-buttons`.